# GemBox Spreadsheet : Multiple font colors in one cell

Tags: excel, fonts, spreadsheet, gembox-spreadsheet

I'm exporting data using GemBox Spreadsheet and I need to format the text in a cell to have multiple colors.

This is possible in Excel like this (found on StackOverflow):

```vb
Dim fixedLength As Long
fixedLength = Len("Employee")
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Employee Some Employee"
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=fixedLength + 2, Length:=Len(ActiveCell) - FixedLength - 1).Font
    .Color = vbRed
End With
```

However, all I can find in the GemBox class is to set the Style.Font.Color property and this affects the entire cell.
Example:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    Color backColour = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tempArray[i+1]);
    ws.Cells[row, col].Value += tempArray[i] + Environment.NewLine;
    ws.Cells[row, col].Style.Font.Color = backColour;
    i++;
}
```

Is this possible with GemBox?

GemBox Spreadsheet Professional 3.5 for .NET 4.0
v4.0.30319
v35.3.40.1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I asked the developers via email a few years ago.  They said this was not available.

If you email them directly, they usually respond within one business day. I think they are in the Czech Republic.

You can open a [support ticket to them here](https://support.gemboxsoftware.com/new-ticket).

There is also a feedback tab on that same page where you can suggest they add this as a feature and other devs can vote on features to add.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of GemBox.Spreadsheet (version 3.9) has an API support for this, see the [Excel Inline Text Formatting example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/excel-cell-inline-formatting/203).

In short, what you need is to use [`GetCharacters`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/Overload_GemBox_Spreadsheet_AbstractRange_GetCharacters.htm) method, for example like this:

```cs
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
var tempArray = new string[] {
    "First Value",
    "Red",
    "Second Value",
    "Green",
    "Third Value",
    "Blue"
};

ws.Cells[row, col].Value = string.Concat(
    tempArray.Select((tempItem, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? tempItem : Environment.NewLine));

int charStartIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.Length; i+=2)
{
    string value = tempArray[i];
    SpreadsheetColor color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tempArray[i + 1]);

    ws.Cells[row, col].GetCharacters(charStartIndex, value.Length).Font.Color = color;
    charStartIndex += value.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length;
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Excel cell value with multiple colors]